# Is there a way to have Windows Snipping Tool append Outlook's signature to emailed snips automatically?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-signature, snipping

I've recently deployed a logon script in our company to standardize signatures in MS Outlook. Someone has brought an interesting issue to my attention. When using the Snipping Tool to directly email a snip to a user, the email does not contain the signature of the user that is sending the snip. Is there a way to have this happen automatically? I know that users can insert the signature in three clicks or less, but that's only if they remember to do it.

Comment: When you create a new email or reply in Outlook it creates a new body with the signature in it.  When another program asks Outlook (via Windows) to create a new email, and it supplies a pre-made body (as the snipping tool does), then the signature won't be there. What email server (and version) are you using?

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/automatically-add-email-signaturesdisclaimers-with-exchange-2010/

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - We're just using Microsoft Exchange. We don't have an on-site exchange server, though. We use Microsoft hosted Exchange.

Comment: Then discuss it with your Exchange host, as what is suggested in the link (and the only thing I can think of that may do this for you), would have to be done at the server.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Okay, thanks very much. The method discussed in your link wouldn't work with the way my signature script is written, but it could be an alternate strategy sometime. Hopefully someone else knows a way, but I'm not holding my breath on this one. It seems this is the behavior when any program accesses Outlook to create a new mail.